# Unable to Remote Desktop into Windows 2012 R2 Kimsufi Server Due to Possible Windows Hibernation

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, ovh

I recently set up a Windows Server on Kimsufi's dedicated server plan. I was able to successfully get it up and running and was able to successfully remote desktop into the server. After updating the server and restarting it, the server had an update error that caused it to crash. After it crashed I was no longer able to remote desktop into the server. I took the following steps to diagnose the problem:

1. Conducted a complete hardware diagnosis(to see if it was a hardware issue. It wasn't)
2. Verified that the issue wasn't from my own home network(meaning its definitely a server side issue).
3. Rebooted the server several times(Didn't work) and booted into rescue mode.
4. After booting into rescue mode, I was able to "possibly" isolate the problem to Windows being in "**hibernation**" mode.

I was wondering what steps I should take to get my windows server out of hibernation mode. I know about the "Wake on Lan" feature but I don't know how to set that up since I can no longer remote desktop into the server. I wasn't able to find a way to do it through SSH.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance regarding this matter. I apologize if this question is dumb as I am quite new to this.

Comment: Getting out of hibernation typically requires physical access to the machine or control access to the host. You need to hit the power button, however that works.

Comment: Also, by default, Windows Server OSes do not hibernate or sleep. You can enable hibernation and sleep, but they are not on by default.

Answer (score 0):

Kimsufi explicitly forbids running Windows on their boxes.  Ever.  At all.  In any form.  They just don't want to deal with the licensing issues.  http://prntscr.com/f8oi68

I don't know if they do anything to intentionally break Windows installations, though.